# How do I get all entries with a value in mySql then loop through foreach

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am wanting to send a message to the discord id(VERIFICATIONLINK), I know how to send messages with ids, but I am wanting to find out how I can loop through every entry that has 'VERIFIED'=InProgress, get the other values in that entry to use in the foreach loop.

The image is how the mysql table look right now[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0kMy.png)

The below code is what I have in the connected to mysql part right now

````
  host: config.mysqlhost,
  port: config.mysqlport,
  user: config.mysqluser,
  password: config.mysqlpassword,
  database: config.mysqldatabase,

})
connection.connect(err => {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to db")
})
client.connection = connection;

function continueVerification(){
  let Playervals = connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + config.mysqltable + " WHERE VERIFIED='InProgress'", console.log);
//take that above info and loop into foreach
//in the foreach, I will send a message to each entry via the 'LINKVERIFICATION' entry which is their discordID
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this:

```js
function continueVerification() {
   connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + config.mysqltable + " WHERE VERIFIED='InProgress'", (err, rows) => {
        rows.forEach(row => {
            /// our code
        })
    })
}
```

Or if you want to const value of mysql select result you need use `promise` for this, because `mysql.query` is a `callback` function.

```js
const Playervals = await getVerifiedUsers()

const getVerifiedUsers = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + config.mysqltable + " WHERE VERIFIED='InProgress'", (err, rows) => {
            resolve(rows)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: In the foreach loop, how do I get the value 'LinkedID' as a const?

Comment: I know in java I can use results.getString("LINKEDID")

Comment: Whats is `linkedid` ?